# Is there a UNIX command that can replace an XML element? (Like a sed for an XPath?)

Tags: macos, unix, sed

Is there a pipe-friendly program that takes:

- An XML document
- An XPath expression indicating the target element(s)
- The desired replacement

? Something like `sed` but knowledgeable about XML (elements, whitespace, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLStarlet can edit XML and is happy to live in a pipe.

```
xmlstarlet edit \
    -N "b=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" \
    -u '/b:beans/b:bean[@id="stun1"]/b:constructor-arg/@value' \
    -v "stun.example.com \
    -L servers.xml

cat servers.xml | xmlstarlet edit -u <xpath> -v <value>
```

XMLStarlet is a set of command line utilities (toolkit) to query, transform, validate, and edit XML documents and files using a simple set of shell commands in a way similar to how it is done with UNIX grep, sed, awk, diff, patch, join, etc commands.

XMLStarlet is open source free software released under an [MIT License](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) which allows free use and distribution for both commercial and non-commercial

https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLStarlet

Comment: `xmlstarlet` was exactly what I ended up using. Not sure why y’all are saying it doesn’t answer the question: the answer shows an example that does exactly what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using/learning XSLT, there is the [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) utility which can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

XMLSH has a command [***xed***](http://www.xmlsh.org/CommandXed) that might fit your parameters.

> **xed** evaluate an xpath expression and edits every matching node outputing the result document